# How to convert daily values into monthly for R

Tags: r, statistics, time-series

So I have a data with dates and hospital admissions. data is for everyday for two years. Data looks somewhat like this:

```
Date        cardioadmission   respiratoryadmission
2001-01-01        12                   06
2001-01-02        10                   5
2001-01-03        08                   4
2001-01-04        04                   6
```

I want to make a table of results like this

```
year    cvdadmissions   respiratoryadmissions
```

So i want to aggregate dates yearwise and then divide year by summer and winter. Let's say i want to see the results look like this:

```
year         cvdadmissions   respiratoryadmissions
2001            21                 22
```

so i want to report the admissions by months, not by each day. some sort of aggregate thing. Can someone please guide me about this

update:

```
summary <- data %>%
mutate(month = month(Date),  # what should i write in month and also in 
date
year = year(Date)) %>%  #same here what should i write in year and 
year(date)
group_by(month, year) %>%   # which month and by year which year. 
summarise(cvdadmission = sum(cvdadmission),
respiratoryadmission = sum(respiratoryadmission) # i have understood this part.
```

Can you please explain the logic behind these in a little more detail.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the `lubridate` package https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/ e.g. function `year`

Answer (score 1):

Add a year/month  or year column and aggregate by that:

```
library(zoo)

DFym <- transform(DF0, YearMon = as.yearmon(Date))[-1]
aggregate(. ~ YearMon, DFym, sum)
##    YearMon  cardioadmission respiratoryadmission
## 1 Jan 2001               34                   21

DFy <- transform(DF0, Year = as.integer(as.yearmon(Date)))[-1]
aggregate(. ~ Year, DFy, sum)
##   Year  cardioadmission respiratoryadmission
## 1 2001               34                   21
```

Another approach is to represent DF0 as a zoo time series:

```
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(DF0)

aggregate(z, as.yearmon, sum)
##          cardioadmission respiratoryadmission
## Jan 2001              34                   21

aggregate(z, function(x) as.integer(as.yearmon(x)), sum)
##      cardioadmission respiratoryadmission
## 2001              34                   21
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "Date        cardioadmission   respiratoryadmission
2001-01-01        12                   06
2001-01-02        10                   5
2001-01-03        08                   4
2001-01-04        04                   6"
DF0 <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
DF0$Date <- as.Date(DF0$Date)
```

### Update

Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr` and `lubridate` as shown below:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>%
  mutate(year = year(Date)) %>%
  summarise(cvdadmissions = sum(cardioadmission),
            respiratoryadmissions = sum(respiratoryadmission))
```

If you want to split to winter and summer, then you can `mutate` another field `season` by extracting `month` and use that in `group_by(year, season)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tidyverse solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

summary <- data %>%
    mutate(month = month(Date),
           year = year(Date)) %>%
    group_by(month, year) %>%
    summarise(cvdadmission = sum(cvdadmission),
              respiratoryadmission = sum(respiratoryadmission)
```

Comment: thanks for explaining, but i have still not understood. I am editing question for more detail. Thanks

Comment: Where it says Date in the above formula it's talking about the column.  No need to enter specific dates.  What it's doing is making a new column called month that is the month of each date in your Date column and the same for the year.  Then we are telling it to group by those two columns, effectively dropping the day part of the date.  Think of it as a pivot table in Excel.  We are putting year and month in the row values and the sum of cvdadmission and respiratoryadmission in the values.

Comment: I already have month and year column in my data. So, in this case, mutate will be omitted from the formula. should i just start by summary<-data%>% and remove the mutate and keep the rest of formula as such. Can you kindly recommend me some youtube tutorial? I have been trying to find a suitable one but can't.

Answer (score 0):

In base R you can use `format` add a year column

```
df$Year <- format(as.Date(df$Date), "%Y")
#         Date cardioadmission respiratoryadmission Year
# 1 2001-01-01              12                    6 2001
# 2 2001-01-02              10                    5 2001
# 3 2001-01-03               8                    4 2001
# 4 2001-01-04               4                    6 2001
```

Then you can proceed with the analysis. Here is an alternative to the provided approaches, using `vapply`

```
t(vapply(unique(df$Year), function(y) {
  i <- .subset2(df, ncol(df)) == y
  c(cardioadmission = sum(.subset2(df, 2L)), respiratoryadmission = sum(.subset2(df, 3L)))
}, numeric(2)))
#      cardioadmission respiratoryadmission
# 2001              34                   21
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Date = structure(1:4, .Label = c("2001-01-01", 
                                                      "2001-01-02", "2001-01-03", "2001-01-04"), class = "factor"), 
                     cardioadmission = c(12, 10, 8, 4), respiratoryadmission = c(6, 
                                                                                 5, 4, 6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```